# Android: How do I create a custom ListView like this?

Tags: android, listview, sdk, android-listview

**How do I make a custom ListView similar to this?**

[image: ListView]

I want to have a ListView with some **US States** like **Michigan**, and upon selection I want to open a new ListView with all the cities in that state.

There are a bunch of tutorials out there about custom ListView, but I am looking for one similar to what I want to do here. I am new to Android programming and I feel its hard to change the code to what I want if the tutorial is very different.

**Can someone please show me an Example here or link me to a tutorial that is be very helpful?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your own layout for the rows in the ListView and use it in your adapter. Please follow this tutorial for more details: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html